# CodeIgniter XSS Clean function fails with empty query string values - Reg ex issue

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, urldecode

Have a legacy app built on CodeIgniter and have come across this issue.

When an encoded URL, with empty query string parameter is passed into the CI xss_clean function, it inserts a semi colon where the empty values are.

So `a=&b=1`  becomes `a=;&b=1`

Ive tracked it down to this internal CI reg ex function, I can see where it does it, but I'm not good enough at reg ex to sort it out.  Has anyone had this and solved it already?

The function is below....

```
protected function _validate_entities($str)
{
    /*
    * Protect GET variables in URLs
    */

    // 901119URL5918AMP18930PROTECT8198

    $str = preg_replace('|\&([a-z\_0-9\-]+)\=([a-z\_0-9\-]+)|i', $this->xss_hash()."\\1=\\2", $str);

    /*
    * Validate standard character entities
    *
    * Add a semicolon if missing.  We do this to enable
    * the conversion of entities to ASCII later.
    *
    */
    $str = preg_replace('#(&\#?[0-9a-z]{2,})([\x00-\x20])*;?#i', "\\1;\\2", $str);

    /*
    * Validate UTF16 two byte encoding (x00)
    *
    * Just as above, adds a semicolon if missing.
    *
    */
    $str = preg_replace('#(&\#x?)([0-9A-F]+);?#i',"\\1\\2;",$str);

    /*
    * Un-Protect GET variables in URLs
    */
    $str = str_replace($this->xss_hash(), '&', $str);

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: Looks like they're adding the semi-colon intentionally. See the comments from your post: "Add a semicolon if missing.  We do this to enable the conversion of entities to ASCII later." and "Just as above, adds a semicolon if missing." I wouldn't try to alter that behavior - it's going to cause a cascade of other issues :)

Comment: Yeah, thats why I didn't want to remove that part, but wondered how to improve the regex so it supported empty values and didn't miss interpret them....

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone else has this...

The first reg ex, when looking for query params expects key=value - the match is one or more chars for the value.   If you change this to 0 or more, then it supports empty values correctly...

Change + to * at the end of the second matching group (the value part)

so

```
$str = preg_replace('|\&([a-z\_0-9\-]+)\=([a-z\_0-9\-]+)|i', $this->xss_hash()."\\1=\\2", $str);
```

becomes

```
$str = preg_replace('|\&([a-z\_0-9\-]+)\=([a-z\_0-9\-]*)|i', $this->xss_hash()."\\1=\\2", $str);
```